# fetching selected item in a form and assigning to a value

Tags: javascript, php, html, select, fetch

I have a form in that form I have a select input. what I am trying to do is get the value of the selected item and assigning it to a variable. how do i do this?

this is the select statement

```
 <Select id="vBankName" type="text" onchange="handle()">
    <option value = "Absa">Absa</option>
    <option value ="FNB">FNB</option>
    <option value ="Nedbank">Nedbank</option>
</select>
```

this is the function I'm trying to get the selected value in

```
 <script>
    function handle(){
  </script>

 <?php $branch = "<script>document.getElementById('vBankName').options[document.getElementById('vBankName').selectedIndex].text;</script>";
   echo var_dump($branch);
?>

<script>
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Avoid such combinations, PHP is a server side language that runs before the HTML page is rendered

Comment: Why are you doing this? Its bad practice

Comment: must i rewrite this all in javascript/PHP or is there a way i can get away with using PHP and javascript combined?

Comment: @talhamalik22 im doing this because im working on code written by someone else using $smarty template